# Wrong time is saved into MySQL DB by Rails' update_all method

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I save DateTime.now into datetime column of MySQL DB via Rails', but incorrect value seems saved.
The saved value is several tens of seconds past.

My Code:

```
Rails.logger.info("Start: Calendars.where('user_id = ? and calendar_id = ?', @user.id, calendar_id)")

target = Calendars.where('user_id = ? and calendar_id = ?', @user.id, calendar_id)

Rails.logger.info("End: Calendars.where('user_id = ? and calendar_id = ?', @user.id, calendar_id)")

Rails.logger.info("last_clone_at update start")
now = DateTime.now
target.update_all(last_clone_at: now)

Rails.logger.info(now.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")) # Output by DateTime.now
Rails.logger.info(target.first.last_clone_at) # Saved datetime value
```

Log output:

```
2014-06-09 14:39:03 INFO last_clone_at update start
2014-06-09 14:39:03 INFO 2014-06-09T14:39:03 # Output by DateTime.now
2014-06-09 14:39:03 INFO 2014-06-09 14:38:00 +0900 # Saved datetime value
```

My Calendars model is just as follows:

```
class Calendars < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Validations
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :calendar_id, presence: true, uniqueness: { scope: :user_id }
end
```

I use:

- Ruby 2.0
- Rails 4.0.5
- MySQL 5.5.37 (from Ubuntu 14.04 repository)

Update:
Other examples of the log output:

```
2014-06-09 16:28:54 INFO last_clone_at update start
2014-06-09 16:28:54 INFO 2014-06-09T16:28:54
2014-06-09 16:28:54 INFO 2014-06-09 16:28:01 +0900

2014-06-09 16:28:55 INFO last_clone_at update start
2014-06-09 16:28:55 INFO 2014-06-09T16:28:55
2014-06-09 16:28:55 INFO 2014-06-09 16:28:02 +0900

2014-06-09 16:28:57 INFO last_clone_at update start
2014-06-09 16:28:57 INFO 2014-06-09T16:28:57
2014-06-09 16:28:57 INFO 2014-06-09 16:28:04 +0900
```

Update2:
Time to execute Calendars.where(...)

2014-06-09 17:22:06 INFO Start: Calendars.where('user_id = ? and calendar_id = ?', @user.id, calendar_id)
2014-06-09 17:22:06 INFO End: Calendars.where('user_id = ? and calendar_id = ?', @user.id, calendar_id)

Comment: Try setting the log level to debug (so that the sql statements executed are logged) - it would be interesting to see those.

Comment: That's good idea. I'll view SQL logs.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible. `update_all` might be "heavy" operation for your DB and it takes some time for updating records (check your logs).

Try to change output:

```
Rails.logger.info(DateTime.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"))
target.update_all(last_clone_at: DateTime.now)
Rails.logger.info(target.first.last_clone_at)`
```

I think in this way you get much "closer" values.

Comment: After I post this, I also tried the way which is similar to your suggestion, but still saved value and actual values are different. I'll edit the code later.

Comment: yes they should be different because "time flies" :) But in second case the difference should be very small I think should less 0.1 sec

Comment: Unfortunately there are still 54 seconds difference.

Comment: please post all log outputs related to this code. How long does `target = Calendars.where(...); target.update_all(last_clone_at: now)` take in console? does it take much time?

Comment: Above log are only the related logs. Saving process are executed multiple times, so I added some other examples.
I will add time between Calendars.where(...) later.

Comment: Added target = Calendars.where(...) execution time. It takes less than 1 second. In my code, target = Calendars.where(...) is executed in different place, by the way.

Comment: Your log should have info how long `update` is going. it is more "heavy" operations as just fetching records

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo and it may confuse you. I fixed it (See [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24115172/revisions)) According to the log, I think update takes less than 1 second.